# Sympy does not recognize that the real part of the derivative of a real function is real

Tags: python, sympy

I want to evaluate Re(df(t)/dt) where t is real and f(t) is real. However, this does not work using sympy.
Here is a example:

```
from sympy import re, im, symbols, Function

t = symbols('t',real=True)
f = Function('f',real=True)(t)

print(re(f))
print(re(t))
print(re(f.diff(t)))
```

This will print

```
f(t)
t
re(Derivative(f(t), t))
```

The two first prints are as expected, but I expected the last one to be

```
Derivative(f(t), t)
```

I checked the issue "simplify does not simplify complex numbers composed into real and imaginary part #18271" which led me to try `(f.diff(t)).expand(complex=True,deep=True)` and `(f.diff(t)).as_real_imag()`, but it still does not recognize that df(t)/dt is real.

I also looked at what `re` and `im` do (source code is here https://henrikfinsberg.com/docs.gotran/_modules/sympy/functions/elementary/complexes.html) but I don't understand it well enough to find a way out.

Would you know how to solve this issue or have a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a replacement:

```
>>> re(f.diff(t)).replace(lambda x: isinstance(x, re) and
...                           x.args[0].is_Derivative
...                           and x.args[0].expr.is_real,
...                       lambda x: x.args[0])
Derivative(f(t), t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, your solution works. I would like to understand better though, and I am not too comfortable with lambda functions. Please tell me if I am wrong: you check if x is the real part of an expression, then you check if that expression is a derivative and is real. If so, you return the expression instead of its real part.
I didnt know about the ```is_real``` method, so I checked ```f.diff(t).expr.is_real```, which returns ```True```. I am surprised that this is working while ```re(f.diff(t))``` does not recognise that ```f.diff(t)``` is real.

Comment: Yes, this should work without user intervention. What I have presented is just a workaround. The check is to see whether the function `re` is wrapping a Derivative of a real expression; if so, the `re` application is removed. Instead of using `lambda` you can use a unary function, too.